# Slide to answer/decline call component for Android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a softphone and would like to use the same component, which is used in Android to answer or decline the calls. Something like this:

[image]

Anyway I was unable to find the component, or similar implementation to use. It's seems highly improbable to me that it doesn't exist as separate component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two libraries which do exactly what you're looking for:

[GlowPadBackport](https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport) by frakbot (Supports API-Level 4+)
[GlowPad](https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView) by navdavfirma (Supports API-Level 11+)

> The GlowPadView is the view that Google uses in Android 4.1 and 4.2 (and, in a slightly different flavour, on Android 4.0 as well) on both the insecure lockscreen and the Incoming call Activity. It's the circular grid of dots, with a central handle that the user can grab to various customizable targets.